# webscraping python ssl certificate

Tags: python, ssl, web-scraping

Trying to practice in webscrape in the command

```
result = requests.get(url)
```

I get

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='subslikescript.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /movie/Titanic-120338 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)')))
```

Change the `verify=False` will provide a warning

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url='https://subslikescript.com/movie/Titanic-120338'
result = requests.get(url, verify=False)  # Add verify=False to disable certificate verification
```

Warning

```
InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'subslikescript.com'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised
```

Try to update

```
python -m pip install certifi
```

No success. Can someone explain in simple English what is happening and what do I need to do?

Comment: Python is unable to verify the site's SSL certificate. Turning off verification, converts the error to a warning. Given what you're doing, you can probably ignore the warning.

Comment: What's your environment? OS, Python version, SSL libs?

Comment: jupter notebook , Python 3.11.5 | packaged by Anaconda regarding SSL -I am not sure how to provide the information